# Passing argument with a forward slash in python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse to get command line arguments like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('execCmd' , type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

Now when I run it from command line like this:

```
$python script.py "/bin/exec 10"
```

The result on the console is

```
Namespace(execCmd='C:/Program Files/usr/bin/exec 10')
```

It prepends the file path to the argument. The user may start the command with a '/' or they may not. Is there a way to handle this in argeparse such that the command is passed as it is without the file directory if the user adds '/'?

Comment: I ran your code and I'm not getting a prepended result? Are you sure you copied and pasted the code correctly?

Comment: Yes! This is in windows. Starting with '/' is always prepending the file path

Comment: It's the OS that's adding that, not argparse.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, [argparse can take in functions for the type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) and you can do something like a check to see if the first character of what they pass in is a `/` or not.

So like:

```
def check_slash(string):
     if string and len(string) > 0 and string[0] == '/':
         return string
     else:
         return 'C:/Program Files/' + string

parser.add_argument('execCmd' , type=check_slash)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with bash as defined here:
https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/issues/196

I was running this from git bash and therefore it was appending the gow path to the argument.
Passing the argument as

```
$python script.py "//bin\exec 10"
```

works and so does leaving a space

```
$python script.py " /bin/exec 10"
```

This is not an issue if same command is run in powershell.